# Statsmodels package in Python - issues with retrieving numerical values of AIC(), residuals, prediction of ARIMA model

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, statsmodels

I have a problem with proper using of statsmodels package for Python.

First of all, I want to retrieve AIC for a given model. I do it this way:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
order = [2,1,1]
endog = TimeSeries1['NMV'] 
fit = ARIMA(endog, order).fit()
aic = fit.aic()
```

Unfortnately, it doesn't want to work: I get error saying that "'float' object is not callable".

The second thing is getting prediction (numerical values) based on the model and residuals of the model (so I could check ACF/PACF to assess whether it's white noise or not) - can anyone help me with it? Neither the documentation is very helpful nor I can't find answer to similar question on StackOverflow forum...

Comment: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma.html ?

Comment: Uff it works, thank you!

Comment: @stellasia the link is broken

Comment: You can try this one : https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma_0.html
Linked from https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/index.html#stats